# Is there anyway of adding latex commands to the labs in scatter3D in r?

Tags: r, scatter3d

I am looking for a way to write latex commands such as $\nu$ and $S_t$ to the labs of a scatter3D() from the package plot3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

On regular plots you can usually get by with `expression()` and `plotmath`, eg:

```
x <- seq(-4*pi, 4*pi, by=pi/100)

y.sinc <- sin(pi*x)/(pi*x)
y.sinc[is.na(y.sinc)] <- 1

plot(x, y.sinc, type="l", col="blue", xaxt="n", ylab="")
mtext(expression(sinc[pi] == frac(sin*(pi*x), pi*x)), line=0)

s <- seq(-4*pi, 4*pi, by=pi)
lab <- expression(-4*pi, -3*pi, -2*pi, -pi, 0, pi, 2*pi, 3*pi, 4*pi)
axis(1, at=s, labels=lab)
```

[image]

But `rgl`, which `plot3D` is based on, does not support `plotmath`.